# What is the equation of a curve with negative slope that gets gradually flatter?

Tags: curves, tangent-line, slope

I'm taking grade 12 chemistry and there is a curve per the subject line and sorry to visually impaired but I need to paste an image as I'm not good at describing but it's basically looks like half a parabola that is in the top right quadrant concave to the right (if it were a parabola and does concave even make sense for curves?)

[image: chem 12]

It says to find the rate of reaction at any point draw a tangent line but what if I can't?  Ie. if the diagram is given on a test and is not drawn to scale, etc, that could be very difficult.

I looked at Khan academy on derivatives and this seems like something that I can get as as derivative but firstly I don't know what the equation of the line is but something similar to x^2?  How would I get that instantaneous rate of change?

Comment: Hey :) Maybe $f(x) =a\cdot e^{-bx}$ with $a, b>0$.

Comment: I was just about to paste this: https://pages.uoregon.edu/anderson/math241/Lecture8.pdf which gets me the "how to calculate the derviative" part.  e^x wow, wow, wow.  I'm going to Google that thanks!